# I am using plotly to create a heatmap but it only shows the heatmap for the first frame and disappears after that, how can I fix this?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, heatmap

Here is my current code:

```
def animate_play(tracking_df, play_df,players,pffScoutingData, gameId,playId):

    selected_play_df = play_df[(play_df.playId==playId)&(play_df.gameId==gameId)].copy()
    tracking_players_df = pd.merge(tracking_df,players,how="left",on = "nflId")
    tracking_players_df = pd.merge(tracking_players_df,pffScoutingData,how="left",on = ["nflId","playId","gameId"])
    selected_tracking_df = tracking_players_df[(tracking_players_df.playId==playId)&(tracking_players_df.gameId==gameId)].copy()

    sorted_frame_list = selected_tracking_df.frameId.unique()
    sorted_frame_list.sort()

    # get play General information 
    line_of_scrimmage = selected_play_df.absoluteYardlineNumber.values[0]
    first_down_marker = line_of_scrimmage + selected_play_df.yardsToGo.values[0]
    down = selected_play_df.down.values[0]
    quarter = selected_play_df.quarter.values[0]
    gameClock = selected_play_df.gameClock.values[0]
    playDescription = selected_play_df.playDescription.values[0]
    # Handle case where we have a really long Play Description and want to split it into two lines
    if len(playDescription.split(" "))>15 and len(playDescription)>115:
        playDescription = " ".join(playDescription.split(" ")[0:16]) + "<br>" + " ".join(playDescription.split(" ")[16:])

    # initialize plotly start and stop buttons for animation
    updatemenus_dict = [
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "args": [None, {"frame": {"duration": 100, "redraw": False},
                                "fromcurrent": True, "transition": {"duration": 0}}],
                    "label": "Play",
                    "method": "animate"
                },
                {
                    "args": [[None], {"frame": {"duration": 0, "redraw": False},
                                      "mode": "immediate",
                                      "transition": {"duration": 0}}],
                    "label": "Pause",
                    "method": "animate"
                }
            ],
            "direction": "left",
            "pad": {"r": 10, "t": 87},
            "showactive": False,
            "type": "buttons",
            "x": 0.1,
            "xanchor": "right",
            "y": 0,
            "yanchor": "top"
        }
    ]
    # initialize plotly slider to show frame position in animation
    sliders_dict = {
        "active": 0,
        "yanchor": "top",
        "xanchor": "left",
        "currentvalue": {
            "font": {"size": 20},
            "prefix": "Frame:",
            "visible": True,
            "xanchor": "right"
        },
        "transition": {"duration": 300, "easing": "cubic-in-out"},
        "pad": {"b": 10, "t": 50},
        "len": 0.9,
        "x": 0.1,
        "y": 0,
        "steps": []
    }

    frames = []
    for i in range(15,len(sorted_frame_list)):
        frameId = sorted_frame_list[i]
        data = []
        # Add Numbers to Field 
        data.append(
            go.Scatter(
                x=np.arange(20,110,10), 
                y=[5]*len(np.arange(20,110,10)),
                mode='text',
                text=list(map(str,list(np.arange(20, 61, 10)-10)+list(np.arange(40, 9, -10)))),
                textfont_size = 30,
                textfont_family = "Courier New, monospace",
                textfont_color = "#ffffff",
                showlegend=False,
                hoverinfo='none'
            )
        )
        data.append(
            go.Scatter(
                x=np.arange(20,110,10), 
                y=[53.5-5]*len(np.arange(20,110,10)),
                mode='text',
                text=list(map(str,list(np.arange(20, 61, 10)-10)+list(np.arange(40, 9, -10)))),
                textfont_size = 30,
                textfont_family = "Courier New, monospace",
                textfont_color = "#ffffff",
                showlegend=False,
                hoverinfo='none'
            )
        )
        # Add line of scrimage 
        data.append(
            go.Scatter(
                x=[line_of_scrimmage,line_of_scrimmage], 
                y=[0,53.5],
                line_dash='dash',
                line_color='blue',
                showlegend=False,
                hoverinfo='none'
            )
        )
        # Add First down line 
        data.append(
            go.Scatter(
                x=[first_down_marker,first_down_marker], 
                y=[0,53.5],
                line_dash='dash',
                line_color='yellow',
                showlegend=False,
                hoverinfo='none'
            )
        )
        
        # Plot Players
        for team in selected_tracking_df.team.unique():
            plot_df = selected_tracking_df[(selected_tracking_df.team==team)&(selected_tracking_df.frameId==frameId)].copy()
            if team != "football":
                hover_text_array=[]
                for nflId in plot_df.nflId:
                    selected_player_df = plot_df[plot_df.nflId==nflId]
                    hover_text_array.append("nflId:{}<br>displayName:{}<br>Position:{}<br>Role:{}".format(selected_player_df["nflId"].values[0],
                                                                                      selected_player_df["displayName"].values[0],
                                                                                      selected_player_df["pff_positionLinedUp"].values[0],
                                                                                      selected_player_df["pff_role"].values[0]))
                data.append(go.Scatter(x=plot_df["x"], y=plot_df["y"],mode = 'markers',marker_color=colors[team],name=team,hovertext=hover_text_array,hoverinfo="text"))
                x_coords = plot_df["x"]
                y_coords = plot_df["y"]
                values = plot_df["pressure"]
                heatmap_trace = go.Heatmap(
                    x=x_coords,
                    y=y_coords,
                    z=values,
                    connectgaps=True,
                    hoverinfo="x+y+z",
                    colorscale=[[0, 'rgba(0,0,255, 0)'], [1, 'rgba(255,0,0, 1)']]
                )
                data.append(heatmap_trace)
            else:
                data.append(go.Scatter(x=plot_df["x"], y=plot_df["y"],mode = 'markers',marker_color=colors[team],name=team,hoverinfo='none'))
                x_coords = plot_df["x"]
                y_coords = plot_df["y"]
                values = plot_df["pressure"]
                heatmap_trace = go.Heatmap(
                    x=x_coords,
                    y=y_coords,
                    z=values,
                    connectgaps=True,
                    hoverinfo="x+y+z",
                    colorscale=[[0, 'rgba(0,0,255, 0)'], [1, 'rgba(255,0,0, 1)']]
                )

                data.append(heatmap_trace)
        # add frame to slider 
        slider_step = {"args": [
            [frameId],
            {"frame": {"duration": 100, "redraw": False},
             "mode": "immediate",
             "transition": {"duration": 0}}
        ],
            "label": str(frameId),
            "method": "animate"}
        sliders_dict["steps"].append(slider_step)
        frames.append(go.Frame(data=data, name=str(frameId)))
        #print(data)
    scale=10
    layout = go.Layout(
        autosize=False,
        width=120*scale,
        height=60*scale,
        xaxis=dict(range=[0, 120], autorange=False, tickmode='array',tickvals=np.arange(10, 111, 5).tolist(),showticklabels=False),
        yaxis=dict(range=[0, 53.3], autorange=False,showgrid=False,showticklabels=False),

        plot_bgcolor='#00B140',
        # Create title and add play description at the bottom of the chart for better visual appeal
        title=f"GameId: {gameId}, PlayId: {playId}<br>{gameClock} {quarter}Q"+"<br>"*19+f"{playDescription}",
        updatemenus=updatemenus_dict,
        sliders = [sliders_dict]
    )

    fig = go.Figure(
        data=frames[0]["data"],
        layout= layout,
        frames=frames[1:]
    ) 
    
    for y_val in [0,53]:
        fig.add_annotation(
                x=first_down_marker,
                y=y_val,
                text=str(down),
                showarrow=False,
                font=dict(
                    family="Courier New, monospace",
                    size=16,
                    color="black"
                    ),
                align="center",
                bordercolor="black",
                borderwidth=2,
                borderpad=4,
                bgcolor="#ff7f0e",
                opacity=1
                )
    
    return fig

animate_play(week1,plays,players,pffScoutingData,2021090900
,97).show()
```

I believe the problem is occurring here because the first frame is what always shows the heatmap, but after that the rest of the frames don't include the heatmap:

```
fig = go.Figure(
        data=frames[0]["data"],
        layout= layout,
        frames=frames[1:]
    )
```

I tried different things all which failed.

Comment: Could I contact you on some social media to send the entire code such as discord?

Comment: my twitter is in my profile: https://twitter.com/dlefcoe

Comment: Alright, I sent you a dm on twitter, also I edited the code here if you want to look here instead.